# Firestore Data Modeling - ChatBOT on Dialogflow

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, bots, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am developing a platform that involves DialogFlow (CHATBOTS) with different types of integrations (Whatsapp, Facebook, twitter, etc.).

That is solved, since it has its own ecosystem.

The problem is that I need to model in firestore to store user interactions with the BOT.

When a user begins an interaction, it remains in the entire conversation through a SESSION attribute.

The data I get is:
userSay,
agentResponse,
agentResponseId,
intentDisplayName,
intent,
createdAt,
session,
platform.

With some variation or extra attribute depending on the platform where it comes from (WhatsApp, Facebook, Telegram, etc)

The storage of these records is merely by way of consultation and reports and metrics, to offer substantial information to whoever uses the platform.

I would love to be able to guide me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) for getting started with Firestore, in case this would be your first time using it.

For this specific use case, the implementation could be done by using a Cloud Function which would receive and parse the request payload from Dialogflow, and update the Firestore database. Webhooks will [fulfill](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) the Dialogflow [Intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-overview), which are used by the function. [Here is a tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/dialogflow-with-firebase-cloud-functions/) using this approach, and [here is another one](https://fireship.io/lessons/build-a-chatbot-with-dialogflow/).

Comment: Thanks for All!

I have followed a guide in Spanish that has solved my problem, this is the link:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309859/firestore-data-modeling-chatbot-dialogflow/